# Transcrypt: How to send an ajax POST request to start a server side job using Python / Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, transcrypt

I'm in the early stages of creating a Flask application and came across a great example from @Miguel Grinberg on creating a long running task. At the moment I want to reduce the amount of JavaScript that I would have to learn / use in my project and Transcrypt caught my eye.

However, I am a bit lost in the documentation trying to figure out how I would accomplish POST requests to trigger the task. Here is the code in JavaScript:

```
    // send ajax POST request to start background job
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/longtask',
            success: function(data, status, request) {
                status_url = request.getResponseHeader('Location');
                update_progress(status_url, nanobar, div[0]);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Unexpected error');
            }
        });
```

How would I accomplish this in Python using Transcrypt?

Comment: Do you want to send a POST request to a python flask service using ajax in javascript?

Comment: @abhinav Yes, I would like for the client to be able to trigger a task in the browser, that then runs some python code server-side and when it completes, to then update the browser with the status. Rather than use JavaScript now (eventually I will have to learn it) I was hoping to use Transcrypt to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proceed as follows:

`$` isn't a valid identifier in Python so use `__pragma__ ('alias', 'jq', '$')` as below.

Apart from lambda's, Python doesn't know anonymous functions, so use ordinary functions as callbacks instead. In the examples below, local functions are used.

Take care to put quotes around field names, so e.g. 'success' rather than success, since this is the Python convention.

Example of Ajax using Transcrypt:

```
__pragma__ ('alias', 'jq', '$')

# For use by eval'ed turtle applet
import turtle
import random
import math

def clear ():
    editor.setValue ('')
    turtle.reset ()
    run ()

def run ():
    def success (result):
        turtle.reset ()
        eval (result)

    def fail (a, b, c):
        print ('Run error:', a, b, c)

    # N.B. The request has to be explicitly encoded, but the response is already implicitly decoded
    jq.ajax ({
        'url':'http://www.transcrypt.org/compilemodule',
        'type': 'POST',
        'data': JSON.stringify (editor.getValue ()),
        'dataType': 'json',
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'success': success,
        'fail': fail
    })

def mail ():
    def success (result):
        print (result)

    def fail (a, b, c):
        print ('Run error:', a, b, c)

    jq.ajax ({
        'url':'http://www.transcrypt.org/sendmail',
        'type': 'POST',
        'data': JSON.stringify ([document.getElementById ('mail_address') .value, editor.getValue ()]),
        'dataType': 'json',
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'success': success,
        'fail': fail
    })

def selectExample ():
    def success (result):
        editor.setValue (result [0])
        turtle.reset ()     # Using old paths
        window.terminate = True
        eval (result [1])   # Using new paths (so cannot clear old result)

    def fail (a, b, c):
        print ('Select example error:', a, b, c)

    selector = document.getElementById ('select_example')

    jq.ajax ({
        'url':'http://www.transcrypt.org/selectexample',
        'type': 'POST',
        'data': JSON.stringify (selector.options [selector.selectedIndex] .value),
        'dataType': 'json',
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'success': success,
        'fail': fail
    })

selectExample ()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of post method in Flask.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/index/', methods=['POST'])
def sample_function():
    # do your server task here
    return "BROWSER Update/response"

app.run("127.0.0.1", "8000")
```

In JavaScript, call `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/` with AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My issue lies not with the Flask portion, that part is easy. My issue is as my project expands and the required complexity of JavaScript invariably increases my progress will come to a screeching halt.I have very limited knowledge in that area and was hoping to leverage Transcrypt to write python code that is compiled into JavaScript.